# lxml python script, how can I remove count of duplicate id

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml.etree

Ok so I'm getting stuck on how to work around this issue here.
this is just a private counter of online people for a game.

After some research, I managed to get down to this code which I added a bit on the search, to get the count of all the images with on.png ...and it does actually work!

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

def get_img_cnt(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   parser = etree.HTMLParser()
   root = etree.fromstring(response.content, parser=parser)

   return int(root.xpath('count(//img[@src="pics/on.png"])'))
```

Now my frustration is that that "on.png" is repeated 2 times in case of the Guild Master is online.
Can anyone think of a way to get around it? this is part of the HTML

```
<tr><td class='tabellatitolo a_dx' style=' padding:10px;' >Master
<td class='tabelladati' style=' padding:10px;' ><img align=absmiddle src='pics/on.png'> 
<a   href='?f=pg&id=55110'>Modernist</a>

<tr><td class='tabellatitolo a_dx' style=' padding:10px;' >Membri<p>(5)
<td class='tabelladati' style=' padding:10px;' >**<img align=absmiddle      src='pics/on.png'> 
<a href='?f=pg&id=55110'>**Modernist**</a>** - <br><img align=absmiddle src='pics/off.png'> 
<a href='?f=pg&id=232720'>Human Slayer</a> - <i>Ti stimo!</i><br>
<img align=absmiddle src='pics/off.png'> <a href='?f=pg&id=68194'>Juggernaut</a><br>
<img align=absmiddle src='pics/off.png'> <a href='?f=pg&id=67121'>XeDiOr ThE KoOl</a><br>
<img align=absmiddle src='pics/on.png'> <a href='?f=pg&id=142638'>Lisbet Irmgard</a><br>
```

I was maybe thinking to use context position or maybe leverage on that "Membri" (members)?

Thanks any hint will be appriciated :)

Comment: Yes, I would look at using that "Membri" as a starting point and then going from there. It looks like the html you have provided is incomplete so it's hard to say how to do it exactly with your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a more brutal but possibly simpler answer:

```
import re
import requests

def get_img_cnt(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    # just take the bit after the 'Membri' section
    member_content = response.content.split('>Membri<')[1]

    # count the number of times you see the image
    return len(re.findall('pics/on.png', member_content))
```

How well it will work will depend on the rest of the html (that you haven't provided). I'd go for string searching (like this) before I start doing html parsing generally. If it works, it's a simpler and faster solution.

Comment: interesting, although it seems not to find the list

member_content = response.content.split('>Membri<')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

this is one of the pages I'm looking at
http://www.uodreams.it/?f=gilda&id=7005

Comment: I see that page in English for some reason. I guess you could use `resp.text.split('>Memb')[1]` which should work whether it's in English or Italian.

Comment: Although it give this error, I understand the concept, so what I need to do is spit the XML till I get to "Members", I'll find a way! Thanks


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print "Gang:" , get_img_cnt(url)
  File "2test.py", line 8, in get_img_cnt
    member_content = response.content.split('>Memb')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`